# Streaming Video From a localhost

Tags: android

I'm developing an android app for my company and I need help with streaming video from an internal source. The code works for outside links however, it will not grab the .mp4 links from my XAMPP file share. I'm able to access the file on my test tablet outside of the application but not from inside of the app.

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class TwoTrimTray extends Activity
{

String VideoURL;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String tempURL = extras.getString("key");
    VideoURL = tempURL;

    Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
    setContentView(R.layout.twotrimtrayvid);
    VideoView vv = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.VideoDisplay);
    vv.setVideoURI(vidUri);
    MediaController vc = new MediaController(this);
    vc.setAnchorView(vv);
    vv.setMediaController(vc);
    vv.start();

 }
}
```

That is the code inside of the activity that displays the video, the code gets passed internal links using the getExtras function.
https://ia800201.us.archive.org/22/items/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet_512kb.mp4

this is my test external link which works fine and an internal link follows the format

0.0.0.0.0:80/app/video/myvideo.mp4

i think it has something to do with https but im not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download one of those `.apk`

1. [Web Server PHP/MyAdmin/MySQ](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nokshaserv)
2. [Daily Update Server](https://android-apk.org/com.andi.serverweb/17942751-bit-web-server/)

Also you can check this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4779963/4385913), there's a lot of information to connect `LocalHost` on `Android` and then use it.